# why my arduino uno r3 restart when plugged in to a battery(9v)

Tags: arduino-uno

i have a personal challenge that is to make a arduino avoidance robot it has a"hc-sr04 ultrasonic sensor, a servo, bread board(for the sharing of vcc and gnd), l9110s motor driver, and two dc motors, and also the arduino uno itself"
but when i assembled it and upload the code it works if it's plugged in my laptop but if i plugged it in to a battery it keeps on restarting and doesn't run [image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: please provide more info.  Do you mean a 9V alkaline cell to power the whole system?  If so this is a common beginners problem where the battery does not provide enough power.

Comment: PP3 batteries are, to put it mildly, complete and utter rubbish. Only suitable for powering smoke alarms. Not suitable for use with Arduino under *any* circumstances.

Comment: a 9V battery contains six AAAA cells ..... those would barely work in a tv remote control, let alone powering a motor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess: the Arduino resets just as one of the motors starts (or should start) right?

The 9v battery is incapable of supplying enough current for much of anything but a few LEDs. When the Arduino first turns on a motor, it needs, and tries to draw, more current than the battery can supply, resulting in the battery voltage dropping below the Arduino's voltage-regulator's minimum input voltage, and the Arduino is shut off. That stops the current draw, the battery voltage recovers, power up the Arduino, which resets (as they always do on power-up), and the cycle keeps repeating.

Try powering it from a more capable battery of greater than 7 volts. 5 AA cells in series, for example would provide 7.5 volts. This won't last terribly long but should work for a while. A second (third, ...) string of 5 in parallel with the first should double the life. Using C or D cells instead will increase the life a lot more.